# Getting selected item of a list returned from an API response that might be empty ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have multiple dropdown list componenet, i fill the content of the each drop down from an Api response for each list, also i get the default / selected value of each filled list from another api respone (multiple respones the fill data and 1 respone to get the default values of all) (2 different tables one that holds the list value and one holds the current selected item ex: settings screen), i get the default / selected value by seraching in the list by the Id of the sotred selected value.
My porblem is the api calls aren't performed in order so it may get the resposne of the selected value and go serach in the drop down list when it hasn't even been filled yet, so it doesn't match the selected Id with an empty list. I tried using await , . then like this.

**ex for filling data :**

```
async function getAccounts(){
  UseGet("Account/active-accounts", token, (data) => {
const accounts = data?.map((account) => {
    return {
        label: account.name?.en,
        value: account.id
    }
})
formik.setFieldValue('accounts', accounts)}, (error) => {
if (error.message === 'not Authorized') {
    setTimeout(() => history.push('/Login'), 1000)}})}
```

**Get the default / selected values :**

```
async function getSettingsData() {
UseGet("PurchaseSetting/search", token, (data) => {
    console.log(data)
    parseSettingsData(data)
    formik.setFieldValue('settingsData', data)
    //formik.values.settingsData = data
}, (error) => {
    if (error.message === 'not Authorized') {
        setTimeout(() => history.push('/Login'), 1000)
    }
    setMessage(error ?? 'there is an error in fetching settings');
    setOpen(true);
    setMessageType('error');
    setIsPending(false)    }}
```

**Select from the return options from the above code:**

```
function parseSettingsData(data) {
if (data && Object.keys(data).length > 0) {
    formik.values.selectedStock = [formik.values.accounts.find((item) => item?.value === data?.InverntoryId?.value) ?? {}];}}
```

**The UseEffect :**

```
useEffect(() => {
getAccounts().then(
    data => getSettingsData());}, [token, history]);
```

I have like 8 get requests to fill the data so i also tried to insert the select inside the get but i have alot of requests so it ddin't work